# Can any function be approximated by periodic functions?

Tags: sequences-and-series, fourier-series, periodic-functions

I'm sure there's a certain generic term for this kind of behavior but since I'm a little hard of understanding I don't know what to search for. Generally I want to know exactly what I wrote in the heading.

With periodic functions I mean not only sine like in Fourier-Series but also rectangular functions.

Comment: Approximated in which topology?

Comment: Periodic with what periods?

Comment: I don't know the answer but I would hope to restrict the set of functions we wish to approximate to something like all simple(in the Lebesgue sense) functions, which are already used to approximate other more general ones. Also, periodic is a very common theme, and I would maybe guess that you need to restrict the set of periodic functions to more useful ones(consider modular forms for example, like Eisenstein series, which are periodic, but I would think it's pretty hard to do what you want to with these)

Comment: By what standard can a periodic function satisfy you it's approximated the identity function? What if we apply such a standard to $x^2$, or $x^3$, or $\sqrt{x}$, or $\sqrt[3]{x}$?

Comment: @J.G. It depends on the topology you are using. I think that these functions for example can be approximated by periodic functions with respect to the norm $$\|f \| := \sup\{ |e^{-x^2}f(x)| : x \in \mathbb R \}$$ This norm basically only sees what happens around $0$ or exponential growth.

Comment: @N.S. Oh, definitely. I was just hoping to tease decisions from the OP.

Comment: Yea, I'm not having any restrictions in my sights. If u want to we could propose Euclidian space but anyhow the question has tendency to be too ambiguous - so thank you for not closing it. I'm totally happy with the general answer.

Comment: @Leon If you go towards almost periodicity, restricting to Eulcidian space is not needed. Almost periodicity is usually studied in locally compact Abelian groups or even in locally compact groups. The notion of (fully) periodic function makes sense here, you ask for the set of periods to be a lattice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer depends on the topology.

Philosophically, in any "nice" topology, a function $f$ can be approximated via convolution with an approximate identity/mollifiers by uniformly continuous functions. Moreover, if $f$ is periodic, then so are the approximants.

Note that if the approximants are uniformly continuous and periodic, they are Bohr/Bochner almost periodic and hence they can be approximated by trigonometric polynomials in $\| \, \|_\infty$.

It follows that if the topology is "nice" and weaker than the topology given by $\| \, \|_\infty$ (which most topologies on functions are), a function can be approximated by periodic functions if and only if it can be approximated by trig polynomials (i.e. almost periodic).

Note that there are many concepts of almost periodicity that are well studied/understood for functions (and even measures): Bohr/Bochner, weak, Stepanov, Weyl, Besicovitch almost periodicity.